# C++ Allegro browse window

Tags: c++, allegro5

Can anyone tell me how to open a browse window in allegro 5 in which the user will choose the file  , and the program will use that file as an input ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allegro 5 has this kind of file dialog functionality.

- [How to create dialog.](https://www.allegro.cc/manual/5/al_create_native_file_dialog)
- [How to show it.](https://www.allegro.cc/manual/5/al_show_native_file_dialog)
- [How to destroy it.](https://www.allegro.cc/manual/5/al_destroy_native_file_dialog)

The first link has an example of a file chooser.

Comment: The docs on allegro.cc are outdated, and no longer updated. Please refer to liballeg.org for current documentation such as [al_create_native_file_dialog](https://liballeg.org/a5docs/trunk/native_dialog.html#al_create_native_file_dialog) , [al_show_native_file_dialog](https://liballeg.org/a5docs/trunk/native_dialog.html#al_show_native_file_dialog) , [al_destroy_native_file_dialog](https://liballeg.org/a5docs/trunk/native_dialog.html#al_destroy_native_file_dialog)